# Asigning 2 integer values to a single item in a table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have this line in an SQL table:

```
Income NUMBER(12,2),
```

And I want to recreate the table in mysql, but it's throwing me this error:

> error 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual to use near '2))' at line 4

---

This is how I'm creating the table:

```
CREATE TABLE Doctors(
DoctorId INTEGER(5) PRIMARY KEY,
DoctorName VARCHAR(20), 
Income INTEGER(12,2));
```

How can I do this in mysql?

*I have been able to replicate the table in sqlite without errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do what your question title states (i.e. store two integer values into the same column), you may be looking to use an array. Databases like PostgreSQL support arrays (see [PostgreSQL array documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/arrays.html)), but MySQL doesn't do so natively (see [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/data-type-overview.html)). However, the MySQL documentation suggests using a language extension to serialise/deserialise the data (see [PHP example](http://99webtools.com/blog/how-to-store-array-in-mysql/)).

Otherwise, it may be that you are simply looking for a DECIMAL type:

`Income DECIMAL(12,2)`

See [MySQL Documentation for fixed-point types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fixed-point-types.html)

Comment: Yes I'm trying to store 2 integers into the same column.

Comment: The example `CREATE TABLE` code you provided suggests it is just a monetary value (e.g. dollars and cents) because the field is called `INCOME`. Do you actually need to do something more complicated?

Comment: This is an assignment and the teacher is testing us by trying to replicate a DB. That's probably why it's that way.